# Enabling infinite looping for slick carousel

Tags: jquery, html, slick.js

I have a slick carousel with 3 slides to show, and have kept slidestoscroll as 1. Now, even I keep infinite as true, I am not able to get any carousel it stands still.

I need it to run on infinite looping.

Can someone help on this.
Sample code

```html
<div style="background: #3498db; padding: 100px; margin: 10px;">
<div class="large-slick">
    <div><h1>1</h1></div>
    <div><h1>2</h1></div>
    <div><h1>3</h1></div>
</div>
```

```html
Jquery:
$('.large-slick').slick({
        infinite: true,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: true,
        asNavFor: '.small-slick'
    });
```

Comment: I think this could be related to an issue: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/2234. Try to set `slidesToShow` to `1`

Answer (score 0):

Just add **autoplay: true,** to your jquery
http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: I do not want the carousel to run automatically, it should move only on click of the arrow.

Comment: Did you add slick.js into your header? can you please provide more code? What kind of errors are you getting in the console?

Comment: ya I have included, my only query is since I dont have the fourth slide am not getting the carousel. I tried adding a fourth slide and I find the carousel is working fine.